# Problem with scrolling in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, mac

I am using Macbook Pro and TeXStudio. While viewing the Tex file, the page is always scrolling back to the top automatically. How to solve this ?

Comment: Do you mean, the pdf page on viewer window? Are you using the embedded viewer?

Comment: No, the tex file is always scrolling back to the top.

Comment: Maybe some relation with https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42709342/cursor.png

Comment: @Sigur The link is not complete. A little picture can be seen. Can you reload it ?

Comment: It is only that image to show those two buttons on TeXstudio. They turn on/off two special tools: *cursor follows scrolling* or *scrolling follows cursor*.

Comment: @Sigur Where can I find them ?

Comment: They only appear on the embedded viewer window. What happens when you press F7 to open `pdf`? If a new window is opened then you are not using the embedded version.

Comment: @Sigur Thanks, I have found them. Now what to do next ?

Comment: I don't know if your problem is related to that. But try it. Switch the left button and scroll the `tex` code and click on the code to automatically scroll the `pdf` window.

Comment: I had the same problem but was resolved when I downloaded this version :http://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%202.6.6/texstudio_2.6.6e_osx_qt5.dmg/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but was resolved when I downloaded this version :http://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%202.6.6/texstudio_2.6.6e_osx_qt5.dmg/download