# TeXstudio scrolling problems on second monitor

Tags: texstudio

I have a second monitor connected to my tablet. The monitor has larger dimension, but a lower resolution than the tablet monitor. When I drag TeXstudio on the external monitor, I have trouble scrolling the TeX code and the other panels. <s>For example, in the code panel, scrolling only works in the right lower half. The right upper half scrolls the log window, which is actually located below the code panel.</s> When I try to scroll the code window in the lower right region, the log window scrolls instead. On the tablet screen scrolling works without problem.

I am using

> TeXstudio 2.12.22 (git 2.12.22) 
>   Using Qt Version 5.12.1, compiled with Qt 5.12.1 R

on Windows 10. I simply installed the binary provided on the [TeXstudio website](https://www.texstudio.org/).

There seems to be a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151930/problem-with-scrolling-in-texstudio), but obviously, I cannot fix this problem like that since there is no newer version available.

Sine this is not a real TeX problem, feel free to move this question to other stackexchange pages. I have however seen similar questions here.

### Edit

Here is a gif of what happens on the tablet screen:
[image: normal scrolling]

Here is what happens when I scroll in the left and right half of the code window:
[image: left half, code does not scroll]
[image: right half, scrolling works]

Here is what happens when I try to scroll the lower right half of the code window. Look closely to the bottom right corner of the gif and you can see the scrollbar of the log window moving.
[image: scrolling in lower right corner of the code window scrolls log window]

### Edit 2

I added [this issue](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1066) on Github.

Comment: Could you perhaps attach some pictures or gifs to better demonstrate what is happening.

Comment: @oliversm Done.